# Transform URL Paths under a JPG FORMAT NOT a PNG to actual image insertions on excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am struggling to find the VBA Code that would help me out to be able to Transform URL Paths under a JPG FORMAT NOT a PNG to actual image insertions on excel. There are a bunch of VBAs out there that work but only if the URLs contain PNG Photos.

I started to believe that it's basically an excel limitation to be able to display pics from an URL path.

if any of you guys know any VBA that would bring (JPG FORMAT) PICS from an URL PATH to excel and place every and each photo beside its link that would be a big help for me.

https://viewworld-files-console.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/113441/preview/IMG_20190327_151722.jpg

That's one of the links I would wanna do that to.

Comment: This is a question for stack overflow. But even there I doubt that you'll find s.o. who does the work of writing new or correcting existing code for you. You'll have to try yourself and post questions if you run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

The following code below works for the URL, but for some reason the server is blocking the URL you requested, it could be Amazon Web Servers?

```
Dim Pshp As Shape
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCol As Long
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A5")
For Each cell In Rng
filenam = cell
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("https://images.pexels.com/photos/302743/pexels-photo-302743.jpeg").Select
Set Pshp = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
If Pshp Is Nothing Then GoTo lab
xCol = cell.Column + 1
Set xRg = Cells(cell.Row, xCol)
With Pshp
.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
If .Width > xRg.Width Then .Width = xRg.Width * 2 / 3
If .Height > xRg.Height Then .Height = xRg.Height * 2 / 3
.Top = xRg.Top + (xRg.Height - .Height) / 2
.Left = xRg.Left + (xRg.Width - .Width) / 2
End With
lab:
Set Pshp = Nothing
Range("A2").Select
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Hello :) I have access to these DATA so no problem regarding that. beside that I have tried the code you gave and it seemed to be not working i guess something's wrong with, (on Error Resume Next). that photo is not the only photo I would like to insert, there are more that 180 Factories and I want all their photos to be inserted , so I would like another VBA Statement that inserts all the pictures automatically.

Comment: That VBA Statement works better, cuz you don't have to write the URL in it, but still it's not working for me, the Format of that picture you put on your VBA Statement isn't JPG it's, JPEG.

Comment: On my second answer I got a JPG loading, try my url link before yours. Your link won't work for excel. Try my code first.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Pshp As Shape
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCol As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A5")
    For Each cell In Rng
    filenam = cell
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/07/20/58/girl- 
    3137998_960_720.jpg").Select
    Set Pshp = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
    If Pshp Is Nothing Then GoTo lab
    xCol = cell.Column + 1
    Set xRg = Cells(cell.Row, xCol)
    With Pshp
    .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    If .Width > xRg.Width Then .Width = xRg.Width * 2 / 3
    If .Height > xRg.Height Then .Height = xRg.Height * 2 / 3
    .Top = xRg.Top + (xRg.Height - .Height) / 2
    .Left = xRg.Left + (xRg.Width - .Width) / 2
    End With
lab:
    Set Pshp = Nothing
    Range("A2").Select
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```